# all of a sudden can't connect to aws ec2 instance (Server unexpectedly closed network connection)

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

everything waas working great with my instance, and all of a sudden i can no longer connect thru ssh or sftp, with an error "Server unexpectedly closed network connection".

My colleagues have the same issue !

every thing seem to work normally (webserver works fine)

I have launched another instance with the "Launch more like this" option, and everything is working fine. it might be related to a chmod on a key file ?! (this is a possible reason found after my researches) But i don't know how to check that !

I also tried to connect from another IP and another computer, same result. I have nothing particular in the logs (it looks like nothing was loged since the day the instance started).

How can i do ?!

Thanks in advance

Comment: to rule out the AWS security group rules, try connecting to it's private IP address from an instance on the same subnet - the default or 'classic' security group allows ssh access by default

Comment: I tried to connect from anoher EC2 instance (Y), i have a response "Connection closed by XX.XX.XX.XX" (i'm not sure they are in the same subnet though). I tried to connect from Y to a third instance (Z), and the connection was successful (same key pair, same security group)

Comment: are you using putty to connect from a windows box - or ssh from linux?

Comment: i tried both. I tried with -vv option from linux, i had the following debug messages (last 6 lines) :
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: xxxxx.pem
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
Connection closed by 52.17.102.141

Comment: check in the PEM file with vim - looks like "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- "  is missing - also if going from windows you need to convert you private key from PEM to PKI with puttygen

Comment: the key start with ----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
I think the key is not the problem, because i manage to connect to other instances with this exact same key file (both on windows and linux), and it was working well with this instance, and just stoppped today, out of nowhere

Comment: did you change any permissions in the server? such as the ec2-users home directory or anything?

Comment: also, if this is an ubuntu box, try logging in with user ubuntu instead of ec2-user - permissions on your key should be "chmod 600 key.pem"

Comment: I might have changed the permissions, but that should be several weeks ago, nothing recently. No this is not an an ubuntu. If ever i changed the permissions, how can i check them if i'm not able to connect thru ssh ?

Comment: please diagnose using netcat and tell us the result. e.g. "nc <ip-address>  22", "nc <ip-address> 20"

Comment: What are you running on the web server? Is it possible that it was compromised and modified the filesystem in some way? I would suggest taking the server down and mounting the ebs volume on another instance to try and recover data.

Comment: nc ip 22 => SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1 and nc ip 20 => nothing. this is a webserver, so basicaly i just installed apache, php  and a few libraries. One question: when i use launch more like this, it should copy all the files since this is an image, or am i getting it wrong ?

Comment: I believe that will just copy the configuration, it won't bring your storage over. To do that either attach the existing storage, or make it into an AMI (not recommended in your case).

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately I cannot comment with my rep so I'll post this as an answer.

I personally would take the same approach as @prateek61.

It's very difficult to diagnose this issue without being able to log in to your server. Linux is very good with not letting people in once the some configuration has changed or been triggered.

Since in AWS there is not console access, this is how I would investigate this assuming that you cannot shutdown the server:

If you can shutdown the server then you can jump to step 3 however I assumed that this is prod and you can't take it down.

1. Create a snapshot of the volume
2. Create a volume from the snapshot you have just took.
3. Mount the new volume on a good working instance where you are able to ssh to.
4. Once mounted go to the volume and investigate:

   - file permissions for the ssh keys
   - the keys itself are they correct
   - check sshd configuration, sudoers etc.
   - check the logs files etc.
   - check if you have firewall running on that server (as this is mounted volume you can't check this however you can check the /etc/rc3.d to see if your the symlink to your firewall is there)
   - sometimes fail2ban or other similar software is running and preventing you from accessing the server again check what is starting with the system in /etc/rc3.d.

After you find what is wrong you will need to figure out how to apply it to your running server i.e. swap volumes, create a new instance, re point the traffic etc. this depends on the purpose of the server and how much downtime you can afford and is a matter for another subject.

Once again I'm posting this as answer as I was not able to comment. If you want to downgrade this, please be king enough to provide a reason.

Comment: No worries, your answer wouldn't fit in a comment box anyway.